# Java, return formatted string of an int

Tags: java, string, int, return, tostring

I have just started studying Java and now I need to make an Java function that returns a formatted `string` representation of an `int`. 
This function must return `"001"` instead of just `1` and `"010"` instead of just `10`, and so on... my function looks like this:

```
int value = 1;

public String getcountervalue() {
   String Return_string = Integer.toString(value);
   return (Return_string);
}
```

This is just a small part of an bigger code. the count of the `value` is handled by an other part of the code. I guess that the `Integer.toString` part will convert the `int` to an `string`, *or?*, but how can i make it properly formated (*as explained above*)?

I'm sorry if this question have been asked before, I where not able to find it.

I'm using java 1.7

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for the implementation of a requirement, rather than asking for help with a specific issue encountered while implementing the requirement.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I know this can be done whit an if/else statement, but that would be ugly locking, so i need to know if there is any better way of doing this. that is at least to me, an issue encountered while implementing that i need help whit. I know that I didn't say anything about it in the main post, but I do in fact know some ways of doing this, but none of them are locking good.

Comment: @Brian u are right, it is an duplication, I'm sorry weren't able to find it when i made this post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a handy `format()` method, provided by `String`. [See Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

In your case, something like this should do it:

```
public String getCounterValue(int value) {
    return String.format("%03d", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("%02d", i);
```

or

```
for (i=0; i<=9; i++){
    System.out.println("00"+i)
}
for (i=10; i<=99; i++){
    System.out.println("0"+i)
}
if(i=100){
    System.out.println(i) 
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever use method 2?

Comment: he just started studying java, going the long way might help him practice and better understanding what the program should do.

Comment: I understand what you mean in the same sense that I learned quicksort, mergesort, etc. However no one that is googling their way here to try to solve this problem in production should ever use method 2. Additionally method 2 doesn't handle any number over 100.

Comment: he wanted to count until 100

Answer (score -2):

```
public String getcountervalue() {
   String Return_string = Integer.toString(value);

   while(Return_string.length < 3){
       Return_string = '0'+Return_string;
   }

   return (Return_string);
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to approach the problem. Java provides a number of ways to do this.

Comment: How else can you do this besides a number formatter?

Comment: @LoganMurphy It all comes down to `printf` at the core, and java exposes that via various methods and classes. `String.format()` for example.

Comment: I wouldn't say this way is terrible if it is for learning purposes though. This code may help someone solve a bigger problem or explain how Java may have solved it with `String.format()`